# How to return the sum of columns from Parse table?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am building an iOS app that saves winning sets in tennis to a Class in Parse.  It saves the team, date, season and number of wins.  The wins column is a number field.  For 1 season, i.e. Summer 2015, there will be several rows.  Team 1 has 2 wins on the 1st date and Team 2 has 1 win.  On the 2nd date, Team 1 has 3 wins and Team 2 has 0 wins.

I am not sure of the best strategy to retrieve the sum of wins per season and team to my app.

I would like to retrieve "Team 1 = 5 wins" and "Team 2 = 1 win" for the current data.

In SQL, I would build a view and retrieve that result.  Not sure how to approach this in Swift/Parse. Any suggestions appreciated.

I can query the "Scoring" class and it returns each individual score based upon the season.  i.e. 2,2,2,3,1. However, having some confusion on how to store them in my array and return the sum of 10.  Code is below:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class viewSumPractice2: UIViewController {
  var seasonSelect = ""
  var winners = 0

@IBOutlet weak var seasonSelected: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    seasonSelect = "Summer 2015"

    seasonSelected.text = seasonSelect

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Scoring")
    query.whereKey("season", equalTo:self.seasonSelect)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

           if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

                for object in objects {

                   self.winners = object["wins"] as! NSInteger
                //this returns correct values     
                   println(self.winners)
                 //this needs work   
                    var winsArray = [self.winners]
                    winsArray.append(self.winners)

                    let totalWins = winsArray.reduce(0, combine: +)
                    println(totalWins)
                }

            }
        } else {

            println("Error")
        }

    }

}
```

//Fixed the code as follows to get proper sum from the array.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class viewSumPractice2: UIViewController {

//var winner = [Int]()
var seasonSelect = ""
var winners = 0

@IBOutlet weak var seasonSelected: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    seasonSelect = "Summer 2015"

    seasonSelected.text = seasonSelect

    var winsArray = [self.winners]

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Scoring")
     query.whereKey("season", equalTo:self.seasonSelect)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

           if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
              //  if let objects = objects  {
                for object in objects {

                   // var winners = 0
                   self.winners = object["wins"] as! NSInteger
                  winsArray.append(self.winners)
                  // println(self.winners)
                }

            }
        } else {

            println("Error")
        }

        let totalWins = winsArray.reduce(0, combine: +)
        println(totalWins)

    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: Do you want to maintain a count for each team or do you want to calculate it each time on the fly?

Comment: Calculate/update it each time on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse does not have a `SUM()` or `COUNT()` function for columns like you're used to in SQL. If you anticipate that your data set will remain small, then I'd do it this way:

1. Query the `Tennis` class
2. Enumerate over the records and store the `wins` column in an array
3. When you're done, sum all the items in your array to get the total wins. This can be done in Swift like this: `let totalWins = winsArray.reduce(0, combine: +)`

If you expect to have thousands of records, the above solution will run into query limits. I recommend manually tracking the wins like this:

1. Make a new `Total` class with a `totalWins` column and a `team` column
2. Query the `Total` class
3. Get the `totalWins` column for a certain team
4. Add the new win(s) to `totalWins` and save back to Parse

It may seem silly to go to all this extra effort for what was once mostly automatic in SQL, but it's really not hard and it makes a lot of sense to keep database performance high and make your Parse requests really fast.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks...hopefully will have a chance tomorrow to try.